# Install developing application and play store application in the same android phone

Tags: android, eclipse, google-play

I had submitted an application to Google play store that is running on the real server.
On the other hand, I am still improving the application with a fake server. The reason of having 2 server is because all data in the fake server will not affect the real server.

Whenever I want to do demonstration with the real server, I have to uninstall the test app and download the real app on Google play stall. After the demonstration, I have to uninstall the real app and then install my test app on the android phone. It is kind of troublesome after doing this more than 2 times a day.

Is there any way I can install both the test and the real app on the same phone?

I tried to rename my package name. But I found the refactor function in eclipse not a clean renaming. I have to manually rename some of the file and this take up a lot of time.
Just wondering if there is any other better way to do it. It would be good if there are some suggestion that I can try.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to manage debug and release version on android device?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4960235/how-to-manage-debug-and-release-version-on-android-device)

Comment: AFAIK it's not possible. See linked duplicate question.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your debug key with your production key and set the appropriate passwords to allow the signing. This way Android will let you update/overwrite the old version.

In Eclipse, select Window --> Preferences--> Android --> Build

You can have your keystore pointed here

However, your key store must use the same profile name and password as the default key store.

Comment: Raghav, can you explain how to do that (change the debug key)? Would be useful information to have in an answer.

Comment: Yeah sure. I normally post complete answers. Did this one from a tablet, so I sacked of a bit. Give me some time to type it out on the tablet.